# System blows up when trying to optimise vehicle movement using control package

Tags: python, optimization

I am attempting to optimise the movement of a vehicle from position A to position B. I have tried copying the code from the [documentation](https://python-control.readthedocs.io/en/latest/optimal.html), but it does not work when I paste it.

This is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import control as ct
import control.optimal as opt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



def vehicle_update(t, x, u, params):
    # Get the parameters for the model
    l = params.get('wheelbase', 3.)         # vehicle wheelbase (m)
    phimax = params.get('maxsteer', 0.5)    # max steering angle (rad)

    # Saturate the steering input
    phi = np.clip(u[1], -phimax, phimax)

    # Return the derivative of the state
    return np.array([
        np.cos(x[2]) * u[0],            # xdot = cos(theta) v
        np.sin(x[2]) * u[0],            # ydot = sin(theta) v
        (u[0] / l) * np.tan(phi)        # thdot = v/l tan(phi)
    ])

def vehicle_output(t, x, u, params):
    return x                            # return x, y, theta (full state)


# Define the vehicle steering dynamics as an input/output system
vehicle = ct.NonlinearIOSystem(
    vehicle_update, vehicle_output, states=3, name='vehicle',
    inputs=('v', 'phi'), outputs=('x', 'y', 'theta'))


#We consider an optimal control problem that consists of “changing lanes” by moving from the point x = 0 m, y = -2 m, \theta = 0 to the point x = 100 m, y = 2 m, \theta = 0) over a period of 10 seconds and with a with a starting and ending velocity of 10 m/s:
x0 = [0, -2, 0]; u0 = [10, 0]
xf = [100, 2, 0]; uf = [10, 0]
Tf = 10
#To set up the optimal control problem we design a cost function that penalizes the state and input using quadratic cost functions:

Q = np.diag([0.1, 10, 0.1])    # keep lateral error low
R = np.eye(2) * 0.1
cost = opt.quadratic_cost(vehicle, Q, R, x0=xf, u0=uf)
#We also constraint the maximum turning rate to 0.1 radians (about 6 degees) and constrain the velocity to be in the range of 9 m/s to 11 m/s:

constraints = [ opt.input_range_constraint(vehicle, [8, -0.1], [11, 0.1]) ]
#Finally, we solve for the optimal inputs:

horizon = np.linspace(0, Tf, 20, endpoint=True)
bend_left = [10, 0.01]        # slight left veer

result = opt.solve_ocp(
    vehicle, horizon, x0, cost, constraints, initial_guess=bend_left,
    options={'eps': 0.01})    # set step size for gradient calculation

# Extract the results
u = result.inputs
t, y = ct.input_output_response(vehicle, horizon, u, x0)


#Plotting the results:
Norows = 3
Nocols = 1
width = 10
height = 10

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=Norows, ncols=Nocols, figsize=(width, height)) #Graph Layout

# Plot the results
plt.subplot(Norows, Nocols, 1)
plt.plot(y[0], y[1])
plt.plot(x0[0], x0[1], 'ro', xf[0], xf[1], 'ro')
plt.xlabel("x [m]")
plt.ylabel("y [m]")

plt.subplot(Norows, Nocols, 2)
plt.plot(t, u[0])
plt.axis([0, 10, 8.5, 11.5])
plt.plot([0, 10], [9, 9], 'k--', [0, 10], [11, 11], 'k--')
plt.xlabel("t [sec]")
plt.ylabel("u1 [m/s]")

plt.subplot(Norows, Nocols, 3)
plt.plot(t, u[1])
plt.axis([0, 10, -0.15, 0.15])
plt.plot([0, 10], [-0.1, -0.1], 'k--', [0, 10], [0.1, 0.1], 'k--')
plt.xlabel("t [sec]")
plt.ylabel("u2 [rad/s]")

plt.suptitle("Lane change manoeuvre")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Despite the effort, the system appears to blow up, as shown in the first graph when running the code.

Comment: What do you mean by "effort"? Did you change the code after copying it?

Comment: What specifically isn't working?

Comment: What does "the system blows up" mean? Did the computer explode? If not, please specify the problem.

Comment: First, I tried to run the code of the link as it was. The issue is that in the first graph, the vehicle should go from the first red dot to the next red dot following the "optimal" path. Instead, it just tends to infinity when running the code (meaning that it moves infinitely in the y axis which results in the vehicle never arriving in the next red dot). Then, I tried to change some parameters of the code, like the time intervals of the horizon and the limits on the inputs, but the result is the same.

Comment: The next issue is that the inputs do not vary at all as shown in the second and the third graph, showing that the vehicles just moves forward from the prediction and nothing changes, no inputs.

Comment: To be precise, the phrase that the system blows up, in control terms, implies that the system never reaches a steady state value and tends to infinity. I used this phrase due to the similarity of the first graph with an unstable system. My issue is that there is no convergence to the final value, xf.